# How to display child pages of child page of current page in sightly in aem?

Tags: adobe, aem, sightly

I am trying to get the output as follows:-
pic-1
....
[required ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DgE8.png)

i am writing the following snippet for the footer component-

```html
<div class="ftrsection" data-sly-repeat="${currentPage.listChildren}">
    <h3 data-sly-test.child="${item.title}" >${child}</h3>      
    <ul class="footermenu">
     <li data-sly-repeat.child1="${currentPage.listChildren}">
      <a href="${item.path}.html" title="${item.title}" class="">${child1.title}</a> 
     </li>        

    </ul>
   </div>
```

And i am geeting the following output-[Generated output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvZmt.png).

The structure of my site in aem is [Site structure in aem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24SWe.png).

I am trying to get the child pages of the child pages of the root page.

The first level child pages  (
Explore, Experience, Stay, Taste, This Is Bhubaneswar) should be headers of the footer as in pic-2. And the child pages( level 2)( Heritage Circuits,
Temples) in those child pages(level 1)(Explore)  should be under them. But i am getting the wrong output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second iteration (`data-sly-repeat`) is listing the children of the current page again. I believe you want to list subpages of the current `item`:

```
<div class="ftrsection" data-sly-repeat="${currentPage.listChildren}">
                <h3 data-sly-test.child="${item.title}" >${child}</h3>      
                <ul class="footermenu">
                    <li data-sly-repeat.subpage="${item.listChildren}">
                        <a href="${subpage.path}.html" title="${subpage.title}" class="">${subpage.title}</a> 
                    </li>        

                </ul>
            </div>
```